# How do I randomly place/set/allocate items within a 2D Array?

Tags: android, arrays, random, grid

I’ve been trying to create a minesweeper game in android, and so far, all has gone accordingly. However, I’m currently stuck on the part where I have to randomly place the mines within the game board.

I’ve tried a few things that I could think of, but none of which worked, except one. However, it doesn’t give me the results that I want. Here is how I am drawing the game board (using a 2D array of buttons).

```
final Button currentButton = new Button(this);
final int bombState = R.drawable.bomb_state;
final Button[][] buttonArray = new Button[6][6];
final int mine = R.drawable.bomb;
final Random rand = new Random();
final int number = 36;
int button;
int row;

//create new Linear Layout
RelativeLayout linearLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

//creating the layout Params
LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

//set layout background
linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(getWallpaper());

//set LinearLayout as a root element of the screen 
setContentView(linearLayout, linLayoutParam);

//create a new Table Layout for the game grid
TableLayout mineGrid = new TableLayout(this);

/*
 * creates TableRows and Buttons using the for loop
 * then add the buttons into the rows and the rows
 * into the TableLayout 
 */

 for(row = 0; row < 6; row++){
    //create new Table Row
    TableRow currentRow = new TableRow(this);
    for(button = 0; button < 6; button++){
        //create new Button

        for(int id = 0; id < number; id++){
            currentButton.setId(id);
        }
        currentButton.setText("      ");

        //storing the buttons into the array of Buttons
        buttonArray[row][button] = currentButton;

        if(currentButton.isClickable()){
        currentButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            /*
             * (non-Javadoc)
             * @see android.view.View.OnClickListener#onClick(android.view.View)
             */
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

                    if(rand.nextInt(10) == i){
                         currentButton.setBackgroundResource(mine);
                         restart.setBackgroundResource(bombState);
                    } 
                }
             } catch(Exception e)
               {
                    Toast.makeText(Game.this,e.getMessage() + "Error : ",
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
        }
        });
        }

        //store the button into the Table Row
        currentRow.addView(currentButton);

        }

        //add the newly created row into the table
        mineGrid.addView(currentRow);
    }

    linearLayout.addView(score, params3);

    linearLayout.addView(mineGrid, params);
}
```

What the above code gives me, is a 6x6 grid made up of buttons.
And the following is where I’m trying to randomly place n amount of mines within the board.

```
try
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        if(rand.nextInt(10) == i){
             currentButton.setBackgroundResource(mine);
             restart.setBackgroundResource(bombState);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this fills the whole board with mines, instead of only placing n amount of mine on the board. I know am missing something when I try to randomly set the mines! Can anyone advise me as to where I’m going wrong and help point me in the right direction?

Please ask me anything for clarification.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically, on every click of a button try to place a mine instead placing them when you create buttons. Maybe You could add to a list, id of a buttons which are mines and only check if user has clicked on one of those buttons.

```
ArrayList<Integer> mines = new ArrayList<Integer>();
.
.
.
currentButton.setText("      ");
if(rand.nextInt(2)==1)
    mines.add(currentButton.id);
```

and in `onClick()` You check if `currentButton.id` is in `mines` list and if it is, display appropriate image.

Comment: Thank you, I didn’t realised I was doing that! Though I do not quite understand how using an ArrayList helps in this situation?! I kind of understand the concept, but could you please help me understand?

Comment: You can use `ArrayList` just to keep ids of buttons where mines are so You can latter check if user has clicked on the button with that id. Example: You keep in list numbers 1,4,6,7,11 (these number were randomly selected using `if(rand.nextInt(2))` part of my answer) and if user click on the button which have as id any of those numbers, You know that he clicked on the mine. My idea was that when You creating buttons (starting a new game) randomly select where mines should be and keep that info somehow (in the `ArrayList` in this example). Then when user starts guessing You check for mines

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I understand it much better now. :) ! Though now am getting an error at `if(rand.nextInt(2))` it says that it cannot convert from `int` to `boolean`

Comment: when I change it to `if(rand.nextInt(2) = true)` it says that the left hand side of an assignment must be a variable. Is there another way to get the program to accept my condition?

Comment: Sorry You can use `if(rand.nextInt(2)==1)`